# Bad Content-Length value pop-up show in ADF Mobile Application

Tags: oracle-adf

I was develop ADF Mobile Application that using Service Interface generate from original web project as web service.

**My Web-service configuration**

- "Find" is only basic operation that in view instance
- None of View criteria

As only find is basic operation, that seems required "findCriteria" and "findControl" parameter(as seen in "Panel From layout" generated in AMX Page)

After drag generate form view in AMX Page and after to deploy to simulator, I was found pop-up error was said `Bad Content-Length value` as shown below.

How can I fix this problem ? as I using HTTP Analyzer and didn't found any request from ADF Mobile Application

[image: iOS Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gratefully, I was figured out the problem with "console" for logging and found adf mobile was using my OSX proxy setting rather than using configured proxy setting in jDeveloper.

```
08.03.13 14:12:41,423 iDash2[3625]: All System Proxy Settings = {
ExceptionsList =     (
    "*.local",
    "169.254/16"
);
FTPPassive = 1;
HTTPEnable = 1;
HTTPPort = 80;
HTTPProxy = "144.1.100.xxx";
HTTPSEnable = 1;
HTTPSPort = 80;
HTTPSProxy = "144.1.100.xxx";
HTTPSUser = xxx;
HTTPUser = xxx;
"__SCOPED__" =     {
    en0 =         {
        ExceptionsList =             (
            "*.local",
            "169.254/16"
        );
        FTPPassive = 1;
        HTTPEnable = 1;
        HTTPPort = 80;
        HTTPProxy = "144.1.100.xxx";
        HTTPSEnable = 1;
        HTTPSPort = 80;
        HTTPSProxy = "144.1.100.xxx";
        HTTPSUser = xxxx;
        HTTPUser = xxx;
    };
};
}
```

So adding current ip address into exception list in OSX Network Setting will be solved this problem.

Notes : My current development machine is connect in company network that applied every client using proxy to connect anything.